# Why am I getting a bad random distribution with Perl's List::Util::shuffle?

Tags: arrays, perl, shuffle

I have a collection of several hundred vinyl records, organised alphanumerically by a catalog ID string. I wrote a script that selects 20 records for me at random from my collection by sampling a shuffled array of catalog IDs. However, I'm finding that often the distribution of records it selects for me is not good. Very often it will select 2 records with sequential catalog IDs, and/or several records grouped close to each other. When selecting 20 records from 800, this should very rarely happen.

I store a list of catalog ids in the `@selection` array, and to take a random sample of 20 items from this array, I assign the first 20 items from the shuffled array:

```perl
@selection = (shuffle @selection)[0 .. 19];
```

In desperation, I tried this ugly technique to try to force better randomness, but it did not seem to make any difference:

```perl
@selection = shuffle @selection; sleep 1;
@selection = reverse @selection; sleep 1;
@selection = (shuffle @selection)[0 .. 19];
```

Comment: I think you are seeing a form of the birthday paradox 
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem  and it is just true that picking 20 out of 800 results in two adjacent picks much more often than you would expect

Comment: Though it's not actually your problem in this case, if you want a better source of randomness than Perl's default PRNG, [Math::Random::Secure](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Random::Secure) can be useful. Getting List::Util::shuffle to use it may be tricky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are C(800, 20) = 3.73 × 10<sup>39</sup> ways of choosing 20 titles from 800.

There are C(781, 20) = 2.29 × 10<sup>39</sup> ways of choosing 20 titles from 800 where no two are adjacent.<sup>[1]</sup>

There is therefore a (2.29 × 10<sup>39</sup>) / (3.73 × 10<sup>39</sup>) = 61.4% chance of picking a set that contains no adjacent titles.

There is therefore a 1 - 61.4% = 38.6% chance of picking a set that contains adjacent titles.

Now that we know what to expect, let's put `shuffle` to the test.

Test:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw( shuffle );

my $num_tests = 100_000;
my $N = 800;
my @titles = 0..($N-1);
my $has_adjacent_titles = 0;
for (1..$num_tests) {
   my @shuffled_selection = ( shuffle(@titles) )[0..19];
   my @ordered = sort { $a <=> $b } @shuffled_selection;
   ++$has_adjacent_titles if grep { $ordered[$_-1]+1 == $ordered[$_] } 1..$#ordered;
}

printf "%.1f%%\n", $has_adjacent_titles / $num_tests * 100;
```

Output:

```
>a.pl
38.6%

>a.pl
38.8%

>a.pl
38.5%
```

Seems like `shuffle` is working quite well.

---

1. See [Combinatorial restriction on choosing adjacent objects](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/288617/447320),

Comment: Thanks for a thorough and intelligent answer. Your test code is elegant and succinct; exactly why I love Perl.